# Swift GET request with json body

Tags: json, swift, get

I am following API documentation where the end point is expecting JSON body on a GET request. The curl example is below:

> curl -i  -b /cookie.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d "{\"groups\": [{\"groupId\":\"1\"}],\"originatorId\": \"2\",\"schedule\": \"1234564334\",\"shortenedLink\": \"http://\",\"linkMessage\": \"Click on this to be directed to\",\"messageTips\": [{\"date\": \"12/12/2018\",\"time\": \"16:00\",\"venue\": \"chelt\",\"odds\": \"3/1\",\"betEntityName\": \"Dobbin\",\"bet\": \"10\",\"messageText\": \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\"}, {\"date\": \"12/12/2018\",\"time\": \"17:00\",\"venue\": \"york\",\"odds\": \"3/1\",\"betEntityName\": \"Bobbin\",\"bet\": \"20\",\"messageText\": \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\"}]}"

I am using the following code in swift but the server gives the following error:

> {"timestamp":1519328960600,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

```
func test() {
    let requestUrl: URL = URL(string: "\(serverEP)/statistics")!

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.setValue("ID=\(defaults.string(forKey: "cookie")!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 3

    let postString = "{\"groups\":\"test\"}"

    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let data = data,
                let html = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print(html)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

How do I include JSON in the body of a GET request?

Comment: You shouldn't. Sure, `curl` let's you do that, but `URLSession` doesn't because the body is undefined in `GET` request. If you want to include a body to your request, do `POST`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1271826

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply, ordinarily I would but the API wont accept POST, is there a way this is achievable as I don't have access to the API source.

Comment: IIRC, `URLSession` simply won't do that. You should talk to the team who are responsible for the the web service and have them fix this. (Are you 100% sure that it won't accept `POST` requests? It is very strange design and I think you'd have to contort yourself to not accept `POST` for JSON body.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I'll see if they will make a change. I get the following when I POST: "message":"Request method 'POST' notsupported","path":"/statistics"}

Comment: OK, so I guess it won't. ;( Hopefully the web service team can help you...

Comment: It is okay to have a body in a GET method. The official specs have changed to allow this. If only iOS did support this... When you have to send a lot of data e.g. to calculate the price of a cart you want the method to be GET, not POST (since there are not side effects) and you don't want to send the whole cart in the query string.

Answer (score -1):

GET requests don't have a body, if you are using a body in your GET request you are not respecting HTTP 1.1 Specs:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3

Comment: Technically, it is simply undefined, not explicitly disallowed. The implementing server, can and should ignore the body of a GET request, but it does not preclude a server from implementing and supporting it otherwise.

This is an area where REST and HTTP/1.1 clash, as the spec suggests POST is the appropriate method. So in this case you can choose which standard you want to violate.